# Parsing text for elasticsearch index and grab index values

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing, elasticsearch

In the parts below, I need to pick out the first entry of the output for each section which in turn is the name of the index for ElasticSearch.

For instance nprod@n_docs, platform-api-stage, nprod@janeuk_classic, nprod@delista.com@1

So I know that they are between patterns of characters like

> { "

and a

> : {
>       "settings" : {

So what would my script look like to grab these values so I can cat them out to another file?

My output looks like:

```
{
  "nprod@n_docs" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.analysis.analyzer.rwn_text_analyzer.char_filter" : "html_strip",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.rwn_text_analyzer.language" : "English",
      "index.translog.disable_flush" : "false",
      "index.version.created" : "190199",
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "5",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.rwn_text_analyzer.type" : "snowball",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_size" : "60",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_period" : "",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_ops" : "500"
    }
  },
  "platform-api-stage" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_edgeNGram.type" : "custom",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_edgeNGram.filter.0" : "api_nGram",
      "index.analysis.filter.api_nGram.max_gram" : "50",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_edgeNGram.filter.1" : "lowercase",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_path.type" : "custom",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_path.tokenizer" : "path_hierarchy",
      "index.analysis.filter.api_nGram.min_gram" : "2",
      "index.analysis.filter.api_nGram.type" : "edgeNGram",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_edgeNGram.tokenizer" : "standard",
      "index.analysis.filter.api_nGram.side" : "front",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.api_path.filter.0" : "lowercase",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "5",
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.version.created" : "200599"
    }
  },
  "nprod@janeuk_classic" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.analysis.analyzer.n_text_analyzer.language" : "English",
      "index.translog.disable_flush" : "false",
      "index.version.created" : "190199",
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "5",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.n_text_analyzer.char_filter" : "html_strip",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.n_text_analyzer.type" : "snowball",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_size" : "60",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_period" : "",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_ops" : "500"
    }
  },
  "nprod@delista.com@1" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.analysis.analyzer.n_text_analyzer.language" : "English",
      "index.translog.disable_flush" : "false",
      "index.version.created" : "191199",
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "5",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.n_text_analyzer.char_filter" : "html_strip",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.n_text_analyzer.type" : "snowball",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_size" : "60",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_period" : "",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_ops" : "500"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

That's JSON. Read the data and parse it using [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS).

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $file;
{ 
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");
   local $/;
   $file = <$fh>;
}

my $data = decode_json($file);
```

Then, just traverse the tree for the information you want.

```
my @index_names = keys(%$data);
```